# Technical Term Specifically for Multi-Example Rhetoric

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a technical term to describe a rhetorical device.
The device I have in mind is when multiple examples are used to support a claim.
(See the addendum for specific instances.)

My criteria for the ideal term:

- Technical, like something you might find on a list like [Robert A. Harris' *A Handbook of Rhetorical Devices*](http://www.virtualsalt.com/rhetoric.htm), which has items like [*epistrophe*](http://virtualsalt.com/rhetoric2.htm#Epistrophe) and [*zeguma*](http://virtualsalt.com/rhetoric2.htm#Zeugma)
- Describes any number of examples, unlike a [*tricolon*](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/tricolonterm.htm), which describes only three.
- Applies to ideas instead of words or rhythms. (Terms like [*Scesis Onomaton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scesis_Onomaton) and [*isocolon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isocolon) nearly describe what I'm look for, except for this.)

The closest I've found is [*exemplum*](http://virtualsalt.com/rhetoric6.htm#Exemplum), which Richard A. Harris defines as:

> citing an example; using an illustrative story, either true or fictitious

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exemplum) says:

> An **exemplum** ... is a moral anecdote, brief or extended, real or fictitious, used to 
>   illustrate a point.

I am leery of using *exemplum* because of ambiguity.
If I use its plural form *exempla*: Do I mean multiple instances of *exemplum* strung together as one thought, or multiple instances of *exemplum* (each potentially illustrating their own point) in one or more speeches?
I want to describe the former but not the latter.

Is there a more specific, technical term for what I want to describe?

## Addendum

The device I want to describe is used in the song [*Like Animals*](http://www.rosenlake.net/er/LikeAnimals.html)
from the musical [*Doctor Doolittle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Dolittle_%28film%29).
Dr. Doolittle backs his claim "We create [animals'] wretched status, then we use it to malign them" with:

> I mean,
>
> Why should we say, “treated like a dog,”
>
> Why should we say, “working like a horse,”
>
> Why should we say, “eating like a hog,”
>
> When what we mean is “eating like a man”?
>
> Don’t we? Of course!
>
> A man of ill repute is called a “weasel” or a “rat,”
>
> A woman you dislike becomes a “vixen” or a “cat,”
>
> A family that is blessed
>
> With healthy reproductive habits
>
> Occasions the remark,
>
> "Well you know them, they “breed like rabbits”!
>
> “He’s as stubborn as a mule!”
>
> “He’s as stupid as an ox!”
>
> “He’s as slimy as a snake!”
>
> “He’s as crafty as a fox!”
>
> Remarks like that really get my goat!

Another musical example could be *Pirates of Penzance*'s Major-General Stanley, who provides us ample reason why we ought to think he is the [Very Model of a Modern Major-General](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major-General%27s_Song#Lyrics).

(If I remember right, *Oh, The Thinks You Can Think* by Dr. Suess, which provides its reader with "thinks" to think about, also falls into the category I want to describe.)

Similarly, web-comic xkcd uses snapshots of online Q&A sites to show to suggest [where birds go when it rains](http://xkcd.com/1434/) is "the universal question."

It is also used in serious rhetoric.
The New Testament chapter [Hebrews 11](http://www.esvbible.org/Hebrews+11/) presents case studies of Old Testament figures and provides brief descriptions of how they showed their faith.

The device has also been used recently on ELU Meta.
To support the claim that *craftsmanship* is not a gendered term, user tchrist [says](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5306/39720):

> As far as I can see, the answer is correct, because *crafts**man**ship* really is no more a gendered term than ***man***ikin is, whatever their origins. We don’t need a new word for 
>   manikins in store windows sporting women’s lingerie, either, and it is a fallacy to think 
>   that we somehow ought to do that. A manikin is just manikin; it is not a man any longer, not even a wee one.
>
> That’s the sort of thing that leads to nonsense like forbidding the use of ***alter***nate or *between* for more than two choices, or avoiding *in**cul**cate* or ***con***notation because they might appear to contain a somewhat rude word-element (well, if French) inside them, or being afraid to use *seminal* for ideas unrelated to procreation.
>
> Nobody expects *un**man**ned* drones to be carrying *wo**men*** in them, either. A “gay-rights” 
>   campaign against the Canadian practice of buying ***homo*** milk would be similarly misguided,
>   just as one driven by a bunch of troglodytes to rename the genus of ***Homo*** sapiens to 
>   something more all-inclusive of women like ***Pan*** sapiens would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ***exergasia***. (Synonyms: *exargasia, epexergasia, expolitio, expolicio, refining, working out*)

> Repetition of the same idea, changing either its words, its delivery, or the general treatment it is given. A method for amplification, variation, and explanation. As such, exergasia compares to the progymnasmata exercises.
>
> <sub>http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/E/exergasia.htm</sub>

Examples from [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergasia):

> Martin Luther King, Jr., in his "I Have a Dream" Speech says
>
> Now is the time to make real the promises of democracy; 
>       now is the time to rise from the dark and desolate valley of segregation to the sunlit path of racial justice; 
>       now is the time to lift our nation from the quicksands of racial injustice to the solid rock of brotherhood;
>       now is the time to make justice a reality for all God’s children.
>
> The idea of correcting injustice is repeated in all four lines to emphasize this idea.
>
> ---
>
> Shakespeare also utilizes exergasia. In *The Winter's Tale*, the character Florizel says
>
> > I take thy hand, this hand 
> >         As soft as dove's down, and as white as it, 
> >         Or Ethiopian's tooth, or the fanned snow that's bolted 
> >         By th' northern blasts twice o'er (IV.iv.360-363).
>
> Florizel calls the hand white in three different ways: comparing it to dove's down, an Ethiopian's tooth, and snow.

---

> <sub>Etymology: from Gk. ex, "out" and ergon, "work" (a "working out") or ergazomai "to work"</sub>
>
> <sup>Further details:[http://rhetfig.appspot.com/](http://rhetfig.appspot.com/view?id=agdyaGV0ZmlnchgLEhBSaGV0b3JpY2FsRmlndXJlGK6WAww)</sup>